# Python + Apache web pages not updating

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have apache server with WSGI module for python pages.

I have index.wsgi file with str(datetime.datetime.now()) which print the current timestamp.
The issue is when I am refreshing the page I cannot see it updates, it jumps between seconds or something, looks like it has 3-4 old results in the cache and it is showing them..

I tried to see if it use cache on the web browser but could not find anything..

index.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import datetime

html="""
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Manual Runner</TITLE>
<BODY>
timestamp: {0}<BR><BR>
</BODY></HTML>
""".format(str(datetime.datetime.now()))


def application (env, r):
    body = html
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [ ('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str (len (body) ) ) ]
    r (status, response_headers)
    return [body]
```

httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /web_manager/manual_run/index.wsgi

<Directory /web_manager/manual_run>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
DirectoryIndex index.wsgi
</Directory>
```

Any idea?!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your index.wsgi file?

Comment: ...and the relevant parts of your Apache host configuration and maybe the headers of the webserver's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body variable is global, which means it is evaluated when the process starts, and is never recalculated. The reason you flip between a few different values its that Apache has started a few separate processes: each will have its own value for body, which will persist until the process is restarted, and different requests are being routed to different processes.

Instead of putting the body variable at global level, return it from a function which is called from your application function.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much! I spent 2 days on it.. :)